# In Primefaces 10, the client side validation required message is not shown for textEditor component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm using Primefaces 10 with *Client Side Validation* enable and I'm struggling with this :

- When using  *p:messages* with **for** attribute, the required message for the texteditor component (p:texteditor) is not showing. Other required input are showing their validation message.
  Here is my definition of p:messages

```
<p:messages id="zoneMessage" showDetail="false" severity="error,warning,info" for="zoneMessage">
      <p:autoUpdate />
</p:messages>
```

If I remove the **for** attribute, the validation message is displayed for the texteditor. But I need to keep the **for** attribute, am I missing something ? Why the texteditor behave differently ?

Thanks

Comment: Ehm, it's a typo or the message id is the same as the text editor id?

Comment: Not a typo, what's wrong with  it ? The for attribute is use  to send facesmessage to it, no ? I'm a newbie with Primefaces.

Comment: I use the for attribute to be able to send FacesMessage from the bean with FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(clientId, message) where ClientId is zoneMessage. It worked fine with all other primefaces components. What I understand (maybe wrongly) is the client side validation message will be shown in the p:messages component present in the page, the for attribute is use to specified where to display the bean message.

Comment: Everything's correct, but you can't have two components with the same id(`messages` and `texteditor`), change `id="zoneMessage"` into something else, and retry. Check also your server log, because you should see something in there, about this problem.

Comment: The id of the textEditor is not zoneMessage... if I remove the for attribute, it work for sure, but even if I change it to the id of textEditor, no message is shown. It baffle me that every other components will show their validation message but not the texteditor.

Comment: I don't get it, if you need a message for each component use `<p:message for="textEditorId"/>`, else use `<p:messages>` without the `for` attribute. Otherwise, please post all your page to see if the problem is there.

Comment: @WoAiNii I have a p:messages in a template for all of my page. It seems that p:textEditor don't behave like the others. Example : My interface have a required textInput, a required texteditor and a commandButton.
Just found something weird, if I remove the for attribute but keep ValidateClient="true" on my commandButton, when both component are empty, the validation message shown is only for the textInput.... if I fill the textInput, than click again, the required message for the textEditor is shown ! But if I remove the ValidateClient attribute, I got both  in one shot. What am I missing ?

Comment: I tried with a simple page, with a `p:inputText` and a `p:textEditor`, both required, a `p:messages` without for attribute and on form submit I see both required errors, with and without `ValidateClient` attribute, so I think you better update your question with all your actual code.

Comment: @WoAiNii thanks for trying it, but have you try adding the for attribute ? Just reference an id that's not one of the components... the p:inputText will show its message but not the p:editor !

Comment: Sorry but if I try with for attribute, if a use a not existing id no messages are displayed, if I use the id of the messages itself (even if it makes no sense) same, nothing is displayed, and if I use an existing id I see only the related errors (for any input type). With the autoupdate, maybe you have some listener or others thing that blank some messages, so try to debug your browser console, to see the sequences of request.